# Does helm upgrade reinstall entire chart or only altered manifests

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, kubernetes-helm, cluster-computing, helm3

When running `helm upgrade`, does helm reinstall all manifests in the chart, or only the manifests that have been changed?

I cannot seem to find any documentation regarding this. Any reference or documentation is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on a resource type of objects which you updating.

Helm itself never make any decision about what should be updated. It just generates objects from templates based on your configuration and apply them to a Kubernetes.

Now, let's talk about how Kubernetes working with objects. Each object has parameters which can be updated in-place and which cannot.

For example, in a `Deployment` you can update it's annotations or labels, but if you will update the same values in a `spec` (which is actually a template for a `ReplicSet`), it will create new RS with that values and that new RS will create new Pods.

So, if you call `helm upgrade` and, for example, one resulting object has some new values which cannot be updated on existing object (in-place), then Kubernetes will create a new object to replace the old one.

That is independent process for each object you are creating during upgrade process, so some of objects will be replaced (re-created) and some - no.

Comment: Yeah, that makes perfect sense. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: It will *only* create a new ReplicaSet is there is a change in the Deployment template. You can call PUT/PATCH a million times and no changes mean no rs.

Answer (score 2):

Helm only sends Kubernetes manifests for things it thinks have changed.

There's some discussion of this in the Helm 3 upgrade notes, and more specifically [Improved Upgrade Strategy: 3-way Strategic Merge Patches](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/faq/#improved-upgrade-strategy-3-way-strategic-merge-patches):

> Helm 2 used a two-way strategic merge patch. During an upgrade, it compared the most recent chart's manifest against the proposed chart's manifest (the one supplied during `helm upgrade`). It compared the differences between these two charts to determine what changes needed to be applied to the resources in Kubernetes. If changes were applied to the cluster out-of-band (such as during a `kubectl edit`), those changes were not considered. [...]
>
> In Helm 3, we now use a three-way strategic merge patch. Helm considers the old manifest, its live state, and the new manifest when generating a patch.

This means if you do things like `kubectl scale deployment` or `kubectl edit deployment`, particularly if you're using Helm 2, that might result in things getting "lost" from Helm's point of view: since the old Helm-managed content and the proposed Helm-managed content are the same, it won't send an update, even though the live cluster state is different.  There are some concrete examples in the upgrade notes linked above.

In practice I've found this means two things:

1. For almost all settings, try to manage them via Helm if you can.  Don't make manual changes to Helm-managed resources using `kubectl edit`.  (`kubectl scale` is probably fine, depending on how involved your deployment process is; things like the HorizontalPodAutoscaler will also directly change `replicas:`.)
2. If Helm (version 2 at least) gets confused, you might need to `helm del --purge` an existing release before reinstalling it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between those things. Kubernetes is a convergent system.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Not really? Imagine you have the code `x = 1; x = 1` vs `x = 1; x = x`. Is code different? Did it set things twice or once? Do either of those answers really matter other than implementation details?

Comment: Well I would assume the code is different. In regards with to `x=x` the value would have been fetched from the stack, probably requiring a few more cycles to perform the operation, rather then assigning it directly as `x=1` does.

To add context to my question. I have multiple deployments for microservices. I am simply wondering if splitting each microservice to it´s own chart would speed up the `helm upgrade` operation, even if the end result is essentially the same.

Comment: End result is exactly the same :) The slow part is not the API operations, it's waiting for deployments and whatnot to roll out and those only happen on changes. It's the same level of micro-optimization as worrying about copying between registers twice.